# Pure JavaScript alternative to jQuery's .remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery

What would be the JS alternative to [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) from jQuery? I have `$("[data-holder=container]").remove()`, but need to transfer that to pure JS.

I know if I was working with like a list, for example, I could use [`.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) but that's not the case for this.

```js
console.log("starting script");

var container = document.querySelector("[data-holder=container]");

if (container.innerHTML.length == 0) {
  container.remove();
  console.log("empty elements removed");
}
```

```css
body, p {
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  padding: 1em;
}
p:nth-child(even) {
  background: #669;
  color: #ccf;
}
p:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #acf;
}
```

```html
<p data-holder="container">
  hello world
</p>
<p data-holder="container"></p>
<p data-holder="container"></p>
<p data-holder="container">dont this one</p>
<p data-holder="container"></p>
```

Comment: try `querySelectorAll` to get multiple elements in the response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) is a pure javascript method...

Then [.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select the elements and [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through them.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-holder="container"]')
  .forEach(function(container) {
    if (!container.innerHTML) { container.remove(); }
  });
```

```html
<p data-holder="container">
  hello world
</p>
<p data-holder="container"></p>
<p data-holder="container"></p>
<p data-holder="container">dont this one</p>
<p data-holder="container"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

> If you want to remove any DOM element, you can refer it's parent and remove it.
>   In your case, as you are using querySelector, it will only return first P tag and not all P tags with specified attribute

You can remove first element from selector  using

```
container.parentNode.removeChild(container);
```

However if you want to remove all tags then use below code

```
var containers = document.querySelectorAll("[data-holder=container]");
for(var i=0;i < containers.length; i++){
 if (containers[i].innerHTML.length == 0) {
 containers[i].parentNode.removeChild(containers[i]);
 console.log("empty elements removed");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Ganesh More's answer and JaromandaX's comment:

- use `querySelectorAll` to return **all matching** `DOM` elements
- use `parentNode.removeChild` to remove elements

```js
console.log("starting script");

var container = document.querySelectorAll("[data-holder=container]");

for (var i=0;i<container.length;i++)
  if (container[i].innerHTML.length == 0)
    container[i].parentNode.removeChild(container[i]);

console.log("empty elements removed");
```

```css
body, p {
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  padding: 1em;
}
p:nth-child(even) {
  background: #669;
  color: #ccf;
}
p:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #acf;
}
```

```html
<p data-holder="container">
  hello world
</p>
<p data-holder="container"></p>
<p data-holder="container"></p>
<p data-holder="container">dont this one</p>
<p data-holder="container"></p>
```

Comment: Your code isn't actually an equivalent of `.remove()` and memory leaks may occur. I don't see the part where you do an actual cleanup of event handlers and other data.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove all the elements that match certain criteria, just

> - Use JavaScript `querySelectorAll()` method
> - Iterate through every matched node using Array `forEach()` method (**preference**)
> - Use the `parentNode` using the matched node and remove it.

View the code snippet below from your code.

#### HTML

```html
<p data-holder="container">
  hello world
</p>
<p data-holder="container"></p>
<p data-holder="container"></p>
<p data-holder="container">dont this one</p>
<p data-holder="container"></p>
```

#### CSS

```css
body, p {
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  padding: 1em;
}
p:nth-child(even) {
  background: #669;
  color: #ccf;
}
p:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #acf;
}
```

```js
console.log("starting script");

var container = document.querySelectorAll("[data-holder=container]");

container.forEach((item) => {
  item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
});
```